# Не отображается SVG из спрайта

Tags: svg, svg-спрайт

Не отображаются иконки из спрайта через вставку use. Если вставлять через обычный img, картинка есть. Опечаток в названии иконки нет.

```
<header class="header">
    <svg width="24" height="19">
        <use href="./img/icon.svg#icon-menu-open"></use>
    </svg>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3):

Получилось разобраться.

Иконки экспортировались из фигмы. И были нарисованы без заливки, а обводкой. При создании спрайта обводка игнорируется и получается пустой объект.

Чтобы такое не происходило, в фигме нужно обводку конвертировать в объект. И только после экспортировать.